# File to Base64 encoder/decoder

Tags: java, base64

I am trying to make a file converter that converts any file to a Base64 String that gets saved to a .txt file. To avoid too high memory usage when decoding/encoding I am using a buffer that reads the file in small chunks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Base64.Encoder;
import java.util.Base64.Decoder;
public class Fileconverter {
  static long CHUNK_SIZE = (long) Math.pow(2, 10);
  public static void encode(String path){
    try {
      File inputFile = new File(path);
      File outputFile = new File("tmp.txt");

      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

      Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding();

      long file_len = inputFile.length();
      long filesize = inputFile.length();

      while(file_len > 0) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int)Math.min(file_len, CHUNK_SIZE)];
        file_len-=fis.read(buf);
        fos.write(encoder.encode(buf));
        System.out.print("\rProcessing: "+Math.round((((file_len*1.0/filesize*1.0)*100)-100)*(-1))+"% ");
      }
      fis.close();
      fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
  public static void decode(String pName){
    try {
      File inputFile = new File("tmp.txt");
      File outputFile = new File(pName);

      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

      Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();

      long file_len = inputFile.length();
      long filesize = inputFile.length();

      while(file_len > 0) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) Math.min(file_len, CHUNK_SIZE)];
        file_len-=fis.read(buf);
        fos.write(decoder.decode(buf));
        System.out.print("\rProcessing: "+Math.round((((file_len*1.0/filesize*1.0)*100)-100)*(-1))+"% ");
      }
      fis.close();
      fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();  
    }
  }      
}
```

The problem is that as soon as the input file requires multiple buffers to get read, it comes out corrupted and I don't know why.

Comment: 1) you should only write the number of bytes actually read, that is, the value returned by `read()` - it is not guaranteed that the whole buffer size will be read; 2) no real need to created a smaller buffer; 3) no need to create a new buffer inside the loop each iteration; ( 4) always read as long as `read()` is not returning `-1` )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do all that. Java IO will handle all that for you with sane defaults. I haven't been through your code with a fine-toothed comb, but the error will most probably have been introduced with the unnecessary complexity. It has to be said that if you're only comfortable with allocating a buffer of up to 1KiB, then you're probably working in the wrong language - Java isn't known for its memory economy.

```
    public static void encodeToBase64(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
        Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding();
        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Path.of(inputPath));
                OutputStream out = encoder.wrap(Files.newOutputStream(Path.of(outputPath)))) {
            in.transferTo(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: We don’t even need the InputStream at all.  Just `Files.copy(Path.of(inputPath), out)` would be sufficient.

Comment: @VGR hehe. Quite right. You can post that as an alternate answer if you want?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on g00se’s answer, you don’t even need two streams at all.  Just use [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream)):

```
public static void encode(String path) {
    Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding();
    Path outputFile = Path.of("tmp.txt");
    try (OutputStream out = encoder.wrap(Files.newOutputStream(outputFile))) {
        Files.copy(Path.of(path), out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

And use [the other Files.copy method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) for decoding:

```
public static void decode(String path) {
    Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
    Path outputFile = Path.of("tmp.txt");
    try (InputStream in = decoder.wrap(Files.newInputStream(Path.of(path)))) {
        Files.copy(in, outputFile,
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, good. The only problem is the original hardcoded path has been left in, inhibiting code re-usability ;)