# Java InputStream to OutputStream

Tags: java

I am trying to convert an InputStream to an OutputStram using this code:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[(int)Math.pow(2, 22)];
int length;
while ((length = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
  out.write(buf, 0, length);
}
```

But this code is **slow**

I could also use the transferTo() method but that would require the user to install javaSE 9 which isn't wide-spread enough. Any idea on how I could speed this up?

Edit: The InputStream is wrapped in a Base64 encoder

Comment: What do you mean slow, do you have any profiler result. If you dealing with huge files try to play around with buffer size e.g. something like `new byte[ (1 << 20) * 10 ]` instead of `new byte[(int)Math.pow(2, 22)];`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? Be wary of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You may want to consider using a smaller buffer to transfer the data. Large arrays and buffers are not always better.

Comment: We need to know what else you're doing. With any luck, it won't be part of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146141/file-to-base64-encoder-decoder)

Comment: You've also gone from a tiny 1KiB buffer in your previous base64 question to a gigantic one: *byte[] buf = new byte[(int)Math.pow(2, 22)];* Not quite sure why...